# When in history did it become impossible for 'qui' to mean "quelle chose"?

Tags: genre, pronoms-interrogatifs

In Modern French, interrogative *qui* can only mean "quelle personne". It cannot mean "quelle chose". But in the past, it could mean either one. I'd like to know when this specialization was complete. In what year, roughly, did it become impossible for *qui* to mean "quelle chose"?

Please, note that the question is specifically about **interrogative** *qui*, not relative *qui*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe encore dans la langue littéraire, autrement fut employé jusqu'au 18<sup>e</sup> siècle :

> [..] son emploi avec la valeur neutre de « quelle chose » (v. 1175),
> encore vivant en [français classique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_classique), est sorti d'usage.
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sup. A. Rey, éd. Le Robert, 2011 ]
>
> ---
>
> Dans la langue littéraire, on trouve encore *qui* interrogeant sur le
> non-humain [...] : [...] — Qui diable vous amène ? (Flaubert) [...] Qui est unicorne, le rhinocéros d'Asie ? (Ionesco) [...]
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, §730 ]
>
> ---
>
> Qui neutre a été courant jusqu'au 17<sup>e</sup> et même jusqu'au 18<sup>e</sup> s. : [...]
> — Qui fait l'Oyseau ? c'est le plumage (Lafontaine) — Qui peut donc
> déterminer les soldats, les maçons et tous les ouvriers mécaniques,
> sinon ce qu'on apelle hazard et la coutume ? (Voltaire) [...]
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, §730 H2 ]

Comment: In English, the specialization of 'who' for persons seems to be complete by the end of the 17th century (Karlberg, 1954, p. 289), so it seems like very similar timing.